# How to define a public static Boolean in Kotlin

Tags: android, variables, kotlin, static, var

I wanted to know how I define a static variable in Kotlin that can be used in other classes that do not final. Because the data is changing.

Example Java:

```
public static Boolean ActivityIsRuning = false;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to achieve this:

**1) Top-level / global declaration**

Declare a variable outside of any class or function and it will be accessible from anywhere:

```
var activityIsRunning = false
```

**2) [object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) (an out of the box singleton)**

```
object StaticData {
    var activityIsRunning = false
}
```

Accessable like this:

```
StaticData.activityIsRunning
```

**3) Class with [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) (as Todd already suggested)**

```
class Config {
    companion object {
        var activityIsRunning = false
    }
}
```

Accessable like this:

```
Config.activityIsRunning
```

Comment: When I use another class
This error:1-> Cannot resolve symbol ActivityIsRuning ,  2 and 3 -> ActivityIsRuning' has private access in ClassName

Comment: I found..
In the third case,
This way the problem was resolved.
"@JvmField var ActivityIsRuning = false"
Is it standard?

Comment: adding @JvmStatic is not necessary. Pls note the difference between "ActivityIsRuning" and "activityIsRuning". use the latter. intellij should then prompt you for an import (class should be underlined and red) (The companion object and object need an import of the form packageA.packageB.Config /packageA.packageB.StaticData).

Comment: @dariushkiany note, that this is strictly for kotlin. you seem to mix it up with java (maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create companion object for this.
Your code in Kotlin would look something like this:

```
class Foo {

    companion object {
         lateinit var instance: Foo
    }

    init {
        instance = this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define static variables in the `companion object` of any class. If you make it a `var` instead of a `val`, it can change values:

```
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        var activityIsRunning: Boolean = false
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use another class
This error:'ActivityIsRuning ' has private access in className

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Todd and @Willi Mentzel, if you like to group those settings under a common area, you can use a top-level plain `object`.

```
object GlobalSettings{
    var isHomeActivityRunning = false
    var isDrinkingCocoCola = true
}
```

and this can be accessed anywhere in the code (inside an Activity, Service, or anywhere) like this:

```
if( GlobalSettings.isDrinkingCocoCola ){
    // do something
} else {
   GlobalSettings.isDrinkingCocoCola = false
}
```

Comment: When I use another class This error:'ActivityIsRuning ' has private access in className